# Генерация случайного числа в заданном пределе с присвоением ему имени в таблице

Tags: access, vba

Подскажите как генерировать случайное число в диапазоне от 0 до 10, где каждому числу будет соответствовать имя, и в зависимости от того, какое число выпадет, нужно занести его в поле таблицы и присвоить имя, то есть если выпадет 1, то в поле таблицы должно быть записано, например, Миша, если 2, то Вася и так далее?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Создать массив с 11-ю именами, сгенерировать число от 0 до 10 `Int(11 * Rnd())` и получить имя из массива, используя сгенерированное число как индекс